# Is there a word for a person who refuses to take a payment for a job?

Tags: single-word-requests

Assume that the person doesn't accept payment either because they don't need the money or they don't think their work warranted a monetary compensation.

I don't think "generous" applies, because it refers to giving away money, and in this instance, the person outrights refuses to accept a payment.

It fits under "modest" but I'm looking for something more specific.

Comment: It's possible to be generous with other things than just money. In the case where they are doing a job for no payment, they've generously given their time and skills (and possibly materials too).

Comment: The are many synonyms for [generous](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/generous.html).

Comment: There is a great difference between not accepting payment (1) because one doesn't need the money (while agreeing that the work would otherwise call for compensation), and (2) because one thinks that the work, by its nature, doesn't warrant compensation. In the cases of the first kind, the person might be called generous, or something similar, as one is effectively donating something of commercial value, but the cases of the second kind exhibit entirely different character traits.

Comment: Your either/or condition applies to two very different situations. Ergo, one word does not work for both.

Comment: One might also decline compensation for legal or liability reasons. Paid work often entails certain guarantees that volunteer work does not.

Comment: This question has appeared on the Reopen Queue, but I'm voting to leave it closed, as there's no [edit] or comment that would indicate that the reasons for its initial closure (i.e. lack of evidence of research, such as a definition of *generous* that shows why this would be inappropriate, or a list of synonyms and why they don't work either) have changed. In addition, there's no *sample sentence* showing how the requested word would be used. This is another reason for closure, as a sample sentence is a requirement for all [tag:single-word-requests].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word **beneficent**, though rather old-fashioned, perhaps implies good works rather more than sheer financial sponsorship:

> *beneficent* 1: doing or producing good ...
>
> especially: performing acts of kindness and charity

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beneficent)]